# How to set up a working VPN?

Tags: 10.10

I've tried to set up a VPN server on my copy of Ubuntu 10.10 with insuccess. Community material on the topic is little and poorly documented ([clients only information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VPN), [scenario-specific information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNServer), [WIP pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gaming_VPN_Using_PPTPD), ...)

What I need in specific is tunnelling of traffic over HTTPS to go around a proxy server that only allows HTTP and HTTPS protocols.

What I did try is following [this ubuntugeek.com guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-pptp-vpn-server-with-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html). I've gone through each step ([here are my config files](https://gist.github.com/704376)), set up an account through DynDns.com, set up port forwarding and set up a VPN on my copy of Windows 7:

- Endpoint: *redacted*
- Username: badp (I also tried delta)
- Password: *redacted*

I've also turned on logging on the Windows 7 side of things and attempted to connect from an unfiltered location. From [the logs](https://gist.github.com/704376#file_relevant%20logs%20from%20the%20windows%20diagnostics), it seems like the connection is dropped right after authentication takes place.

Where did I go wrong?  Was there a guide on the Ubuntu official resources I could've tried instead?

Comment: Obviously, by the best of my knowledge, the redacted bits are accurate.

Comment: List the contents of firewall tables is pretty helpful for solving your question.Just add the `sudo iptables -t filter -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -L` results to above description.

Comment: @kit.yang [Here you are](https://gist.github.com/704376#file_iptables%20_l), it's pretty uneventful.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use OpenVPN? It's very easy both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Sure, but how would I do that? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward guide: http://rootmanager.com/ubuntu-ipsec-l2tp-windows-domain-auth/setting-up-openswan-xl2tpd-with-native-windows-clients.html but it doesn't cover tunneling it over http/https

another solution is here: http://www.exiledmind.net/vpn-tunnel/ this maps EXACTLY to what you are trying to do.

I prefer openswan since openvpn is client number limited now

if the auth is succeeding but the tunnel isn't formed this usually means the two end-points can't agree on tunnel mode and/or crypto system.  another possibility is a routing problem where the near and far networks are on the same private subnet and your traffic gets dropped because it doesn't know to transit the vpn link.