# How to set up VPN?

Tags: 10.10, vpn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up a working VPN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13754/how-to-set-up-a-working-vpn)

I am currently in a country where I can't access some social sites like meetme.com and other sites. Since I am totally new to Ubuntu I don't know how to setup a vpn.
I searched a lot in software-center but I couldn't find any vpn software. And I don't know which vpn to use. I tried using hotspot shield(.exe) with  wine but it doesn't work and it opens in the bottom right corner a white window[image: this is it]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/13754/44179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off:
Are you sure you really need a VPN? I mean you can use a "cgi proxy" to view most sites even if they are somehow blocked normally; or even better if you have another box online with an sshd you can tunnel your internet connection through that (I generally prefer this method).

Second:
By VPN do you mean a VPN server / a VPN client / an open VPN network to connect to?
In the first and second cases look through the software center, in the third case look into [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/).

Comment: CAn u please explain cgi proxy for me?
and by vpn i mean a vpn software just like 'hotspot shield'

Comment: one last request....pleaase vote up my question

Answer (score 3):

The most common solution is `openvpn`. You have some information in the [Ubuntu web](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN).

Comment: I installed openvpn but dont know how to use it

Comment: At the end of the article, you have a link to a how-to article in the official openvpn page: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

Comment: can u please vote up my question?

Comment: thanks but open vpn has a lot of steps.......however it still counts